# Интернационализация GWT-приложений?

Tags: веб-программирование, java, интернационализация, gwt

Какие можете предложить способы интернационализации web-приложений на GWT?
Работаем на Eclipse 3.7, GWT 2.4, SmartGWT 2.5.

Comment: все довольно подробно <http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n.html>

Comment: У google документация хорошая, однако было бы неплохо обновить ее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У них есть собственный механизм интернационализации. Из bundl-ов генерируются классы, где каждая строка будет методом. Ну и ещё есть несколько механизмов. Подробнее [здесь](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n.html).